# How do I prevent an object from being persisted using Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I've an object model I'm persisting to a SQL Compact database using EF 4.2. One of my classes has a flag I use to determine if the object was modified. If the object was never changed from its default value I do not wish to save it to the database. Is there a way I can configure `DbModelBuilder` to toss out objects based on this property (it's a bool)?  The other option I am considering is overriding `DbContext.SaveChanges` and just removing the object from the `DbSet` if the object was not modified. Suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking here. Are you trying to inhibit saving of unmodified objects? My understanding is that EF does not save unmodified objects.  See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896269.aspx

Comment: Actually I am creating objects and tossing out those which are never changed before it gets saved.  So I'm not sure if the change tracking will work.  Thanks for the link though, interesting stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the attached object was not modified it will not be saved to database. `DbContext` has its own change tracking mechanism and it will not use your custom property.

Comment: Good point, but yet the structure of my program causes the object to be created up front before I ultimately know if it should be saved.  At that point I think EF will add it to the database if I don't specifically check my flag and toss it.  I've yet to experiment with it though.

Comment: If you don't want to save object don't attach / add it to the context in the first place. It looks like you are trying to solve issue caused by bad program design or bad EF usage (or both because EF makes requirements on your program design).

Comment: Again, good point.  For now I'm stuck with the design and just working around it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add this to your business logic? What I mean is, why should EF deal with this? It could be as simple as:

```
if myObj.WasModified
    context.SaveChanges()

else
    do nothing
```

Not to mention EF won't do anything if the object wasn't modified anyway